# How to get the real UTC timestamp (client independent)?

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime, timestamp

Is there a way to get the **real** current UTC timestamp without being dependent on the client's time which might not be set correctly on every client?

I know with JavaScript's `getTime()` I can get the UTC timestamp in milliseconds. It's independent of the client's timezone, but I think it's dependent of the client's current time.

I'm trying to make a live clock that shows the real UTC time, so it shouldn't matter if the client's time is set correctly or not for it to be correct.

Comment: You should look into NTP or any of the other network time protocols.

Comment: Please review my edit, is a basic server-sync real time clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get this JSON:

```
http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json
```

Or

```
http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now
```

Also you can get it from your own server if you have one.

For an example of the first one (with interval):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="time">Click the button</div>
<button id="gettime">Get the time</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT (With JQuery):**

```
$("#gettime").click(function() {
setInterval(ajaxCalltoGetTime, 1000);
});


function ajaxCalltoGetTime() {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
    url: 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    $("#time").html(msg.hour + ":" + msg.minute + ":" + msg.second );
});
```

JSFiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/op8xdsrv/

Comment: I don't think your JSFiddle is working (at least not on Chrome).

Comment: Is working, that is not working is the feed of the hour: http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json

Comment: But there is a lot of sites with this service.

Answer (score 2):

You can trust your server's clock*. Just send the current UNIX timestamp from the server to the client.  Then can use in JavaScript [**`Date(value)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) constructor.

```
<script>
var serverTime = new Date(<? php echo time(); ?> * 1000);
console.log(
    serverTime.getUTCFullYear(), 
    serverTime.getUTCMonth() + 1, 
    serverTime.getUTCDate(), 
    serverTime.getUTCHours(), 
    serverTime.getUTCMinutes(), 
    serverTime.getUTCSeconds()
);
// use this time to seed your JavaScript clock
</script>
```

* *Generally speaking*, servers periodically synchronize their time with a time provider.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[timeanddate api](https://services.timeanddate.com/api/doc/chap-auth.html)** to get date and time without dependending on client machine or your server in php. Then send it to javascript.