# 3 Week Cycle in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, web

I am currently learning JavaScript and I'm trying to make a HTML Web App that display a menu for my schools canteen.
My school has a 3 week cycle of menus, like so:

```
| Week | Menu |
| 1    | 1    |
| 2    | 2    |
| 3    | 3    |
| 4    | 1    |
| 5    | 2    |
| 6    | 3    |
```

I have no idea how to do this in JavaScript, so a full explanation would be great!

EDIT: Okay, didn't explain very well;

The menu will be displayed as a table. I know basic JavaScript, but not much on 'time'.

The more detailed the explanation the better!

EDIT 2: I will have 3 different tables, and I want a different to display every week, in a 3 week cycle. Really sorry about my poor explanation.

Comment: A full explanation? Do I get a full salary from fully teaching you?

Comment: Non-sarcasm: please read the mass-available tutorials the internet has to offer. We can help with issues, but we're not here to teach from the ground up

Comment: What are you looking to build? A table? Need you to be more specific as to what this menu looks like

Comment: Okay, sorry. I know basic JavaScript, but not a lot on 'time'. And yes, the menu will be displayed as a table. @Xenyal

Comment: @The3No0b You can have a table with 6 columns, one for each week. I'm guessing you want the contents of the column to repeat for every three columns? That isn't really a problem concerning `time` but (correct me if I'm mistaken) more of a "How do you format `tablerow` tags to repeat with an index?"-kind of question.

Comment: @Xenyal, sorry I want 3 different menus in 3 different tables, and I want a different table to display every week, in a 3 week cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this would be with AngularJS. But maybe that's a bit more advanced. Anyway the good thing here is that you don't have to do any DOM manipulations.
That's the job of Angular's two-way data binding.

I did two version one with a directive and one just with a controller. The one with the controller is easier to understand. But I would prefer the directive approach. That's why I post it here.

The controller variant is also working and can be found in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/atLkmwv9/).

Also one good thing of AngularJS are filters `{{menu.price | currency}}`. That's why the prices are correctly displayed with the currency filter (e.g. $3.50). No additional programming required.

(If you prefer jsFiddle, here is the link to the directive approach, same version as below: [Directive Menu angularJS](http://jsfiddle.net/atLkmwv9/7/))

The lines of code are very simillar to the jQuery version around 68 code lines (if you move the HTML template of the Angular directive in a separate file).

```js
"use strict";

var app = angular.module('MenuApp', []);

// possible improvements:
// - menues data in separate JSON file
// - menu template in separate HTML template file 
//   (use templateURL instead of template)

app.directive('menu', function(){  
    return {
        scope: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
            // Initialization
            var menues = [{ 'name': 'pasta week',
                            'meals': [
                            {'name': 'noodles', 'price': 2.5},
                            {'name': 'pizza',   'price': 8.0}, 
                            {'name': 'lasagne', 'price': 5.0}]     
                          },
                          { 'name': 'beef week',
                            'meals': [
                            {'name': 'Club steak', 'price': 10},
                            {'name': 'Entrecote',   'price': 15}, 
                            {'name': 'Filet', 'price': 15}] 
                          },
                          { 'name': 'veggie week',
                            'meals': [
                            {'name': 'salad', 'price': 3},
                            {'name': 'tofu burger',   'price': 4}, 
                            {'name': 'greenstuff', 'price': 3.5}]
                          }
                        ];

            var startWeek = 47; // week of year that start with menu 1
            
            // Event handlers
            var that = this;
            
            $scope.onWeekChange = function () {
                that.changeMenu($scope.selectedWeek);
            };
            
            this.changeMenu = function(selection) {
                var currentWeek = selection-1;  // -1 because array start with index 0
                var menu = menues[currentWeek]; // store menu of week in variable
                $scope.weekMenue = menu;
            }
            
            // getWeek (modified)
            // source from here http://zerosixthree.se/snippets/get-week-of-the-year-with-jquery/
            var getWeek = function() {
                var curdate = new Date();
                var onejan = new Date(curdate.getFullYear(),0,1);
                var today = new Date(curdate.getFullYear(),curdate.getMonth(),curdate.getDate());
                var dayOfYear = ((today - onejan + 86400000)/86400000);
                return Math.ceil(dayOfYear/7);
            };

            var setCurrentWeek = function() {
                var currentWeek = getWeek();
                var menuOfWeek = ( ( currentWeek - startWeek ) % 3 ) + 1; 
                //+1 because calculation result in 0 for cureent week and it should be 1
                return menuOfWeek;
            };
            
            this.init = function() { 
                $scope.selectedWeek = setCurrentWeek();
                this.changeMenu($scope.selectedWeek);
            };
            
            this.init();                    
        },
        template:
            '<h2 id="weekName">{{weekMenue.name}}</h2>' +
            '<ul id="menu" class="list-group">' +
            '   <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="menu in weekMenue.meals">'  +
            '   {{menu.name}}<span class="price">{{menu.price | currency}}</span>' +
            '   </li>' +
            '</ul>'+  
            '<b>Choose your week:</b>' +
            '<select name="week" size="1" ng-model="selectedWeek" ng-change="onWeekChange()">' +
            '   <option>1</option>' +
            '   <option>2</option>' +
            '   <option>3</option>' +
            '</select>'
    };
});
```

```css
body {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
#menu {
    width: 50%;
}
.price{
    float:right;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div ng-app="MenuApp">
    <h1>Menu of the week</h1>
    <menu></menu>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like the best way to do it, but can I make it so you don't have to pick a week yourself, it will detect it?

Comment: You have to set just the start week so the script knows where the three week cycle starts. That's done once and then the weeks are automatically detected. One thing I would improve at the script, I would use a time server to get the current date instead of relying on the client date is correct. Check out this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019104/how-to-get-the-real-utc-timestamp-client-independent/27019252#27019252) and the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do something like this is to store your menu data in a JSON file or JSON object (done in the example below) and then display the menu in an unordered list (or table).

The selection of the week can be done automatically and it displays the correct menu if the date of the computer of the client is correctly set. (Maybe using the date from a time server or from your hosting server would be better.)

The following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jmosme0/1/) should do the job (it's the same code like the code below).

If you like to test that the week selection on page load is working, you can modify the variable `startWeek` to 46,45,43,...

The next and final thing you need to check is the number format of the price that's not implemented in the example but that should be no problem.

```js
var menues = [ { 'name': 'pasta week',
                'meals': [
                    {'name': 'noodles', 'price': 2.5},
                    {'name': 'pizza',   'price': 8.0}, 
                    {'name': 'lasagne', 'price': 5.0}]     
               },
               { 'name': 'beef week',
                 'meals': [
                    {'name': 'Club steak', 'price': 10},
                    {'name': 'Entrecote',   'price': 15}, 
                    {'name': 'Filet', 'price': 15}] 
               },
               { 'name': 'veggie week',
                'meals': [
                    {'name': 'salad', 'price': 3},
                    {'name': 'tofu burger',   'price': 4}, 
                    {'name': 'greenstuff', 'price': 3.5}]
               }
             ];

var startWeek = 47; // week of year that start with menu 1

$("select[name=week]").change(function() {
  changeMenu(this.value); //pass current selection value to function
});

function changeMenu(selection) {
  //console.log(selection);         // just for debugging
  var currentWeek = selection - 1; // -1 because array start with index 0
  var menu = menues[currentWeek]; // store menu of week in variable
  var weekName = menu.name;
  var weekMenues = menu.meals;
  var $menuTable = $("#menu"); // store jQuery object of ul list

  // set value of select box -> can be wrong if week selected from js
  $("select[name=week]").val(selection);


  $("#weekName").html(weekName); // add week name to h2 tag
  $menuTable.empty(); // clear ul to always start with an empty ul

  for (var i = 0; i < weekMenues.length; i++) {
    // loop through list and add meals to ul list
    $menuTable.append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + weekMenues[i].name + "<p class='price'>" + weekMenues[i].price + " $</li>");
  }
}

// extend date to have a getWeek method
// source from here http://zerosixthree.se/snippets/get-week-of-the-year-with-jquery/
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
  var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  var today = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate());
  var dayOfYear = ((today - onejan + 86400000) / 86400000);
  return Math.ceil(dayOfYear / 7)
};

// the following code runs on page load to setup menu
// get current week
var today = new Date();
var currentWeek = today.getWeek();

// check which menu to choose
var menuOfWeek = ((currentWeek - startWeek) % 3) + 1;
//+1 because calculation result in 0 for cureent week and it should be 1
//console.log(menuOfWeek);

// select week on page load
changeMenu(menuOfWeek);
```

```css
body {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#menu {
  width: 50%;
}
.price {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Menu of the week</h1>
<h2 id="weekName"></h2>
<ul id='menu' class="list-group">
</ul>

<b>Choose your week:</b>
<select name="week" size="1">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```